# Сортировка массива массивов perl

Tags: массивы, perl

Имеется массив массивов:

```
dump(@test) 
(
  ["hello1", "world1"],
  ["hello2", "world123"],
  ["hello3", "world3"],
  ["hello3", "world213"],
  ["hello3", "world0"],
  ["hello1", "world9"],
  ["hello20", "world8"],
  ["hello20", "world7"],
)
```

Как мне из этого получить все записи сначала для hello1, потом hello2 и т.п.?
Например в файл вида

```
[hello1]
world1
world9
[hello2]
world213
etc
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Думаю надо преобразовать его в хеш массивов и потом уже с ним работать:

```
my(@test)=(  ["hello1", "world1"], ["hello2", "world123"], ["hello3", "world3"], ["hello3", "world213"],
         ["hello3", "world0"], ["hello1", "world9"],   ["hello20", "world8"],  ["hello20", "world7"] );

my($k,$v,@v,%hash);
foreach $v (@test) {
 @v=@{$v};
 $hash{$v[0]}[@{$hash{$v[0]}}]=$v[1];
}
foreach $k (sort keys(%hash)) {
 print "[$k]\n";
 foreach $v (@{$hash{$k}})
  {
   print "$v\n";
  }
}
```

Только `sort` надо будет скормить свой обработчик, который корректно отсортирует строки.

Answer (score 1):

Согласен насчет преобразовать в хеш, но вот сортировка через функцию может оказаться не столь удобной. Если там порядок строк не зависит от алфавита, или еще чего нибудь упорядоченного, то можно убить кучу времени на реализацию сортера. Почему бы не использовать массив ключей как дополнение?

```
my @list = (
["hello1", "world1"],
["hello2", "world123"],
["hello3", "world3"],
["hello3", "world213"],
["hello3", "world0"],
["hello1", "world9"],
["hello20", "world8"],
["hello20", "world7"],
);
my %h;
my @order;
foreach my $i (@list){
    my $key = $i->[0];
    unless($h{$key}){
        $h{$key} = [];
        push @order, $key;
    }
    push $h{$key}, $i->[1];
}

# show result
while( my $k = shift @order ){
    print "[$k]\n";
    print "$_\n" foreach @{ $h{$k} };
}
```

Comment: Блин, когда мне книгу по perl привезут, вот видно, у вас код гораздо красивее, чем у меня выходит :) Только `push $h{$key}, $i->[1]` не работает, надо `push @{$h{$key}}, $i->[1]`. А массив к сожалению вам поможет только из за того, что изначальные данные отсортированы, если в изначальных данных hello20 в начале - то и на выводе будет в начале

Comment: Да, насчет @{$h{$key}} это я протупил. А вот насчет сортировки я исходил из того что важно придерживаться такого же порядка как и во входных данных. Ну а ежели надо по алфавиту, то sort в помощь :)

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @test = (
  ["hello1", "world1"],
  ["hello2", "world123"],
  ["hello3", "world3"],
  ["hello3", "world213"],
  ["hello3", "world0"],
  ["hello1", "world9"],
  ["hello20", "world8"],
  ["hello20", "world7"],
);

my %h; 
map { push do { $h{ $_->[0] } //= [] }, $_->[1] } @test;
map { print "[$_]\n" , join("\n", sort @{ $h{$_} }), "\n" } sort keys %h;

__END__

Выдаст: 

[hello1]
world1
world9
[hello2]
world123
[hello20]
world7
world8
[hello3]
world0
world213
world3
```

Answer (score 0):

Для подгрузки файла заданного формата используйте модуль [`YAML`](http://search.cpan.org/~ingy/YAML-1.15/lib/YAML.pod) и на выходе вы получите то, что вам нужно.